# How to move files to Folder and Sub folder based on file name using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, directory, subdirectory

Powershell beginner here. I tried coding this using Powershell, but without getting anywhere.

I have a list of `Wav` files that I need to move automatically into a folder based on the file name.

```
20190822091227_202123545.wav

20190822080957_202123545.wav
```

The file name determines the folder structure - Example

```
2019(This is the Year)08(This is the Month)22(This is the Day)_202123545.wav
```

So the folder structure will be

```
C:\Archive\2019(Year)\201908(YearMonth)\22(Day)
C:\Archive\2019\201908\22
```

and the `wav` files will move to that folder - In this case its 22

I have tried this code that I found here on Stackoverflow and added my own, but its giving me errors.

```bsh
$SourceFolder = Set-Location "C:\CR\Files"
$targetFolder = "C:\Archive\CR_Dev\Test_Folder"
$numFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter *.WAV).Count
$i=0

clear-host;
Write-Host 'This script will copy ' $numFiles ' files from ' $SourceFolder ' to ' $targetFolder
Read-host -prompt 'Press enter to start copying the files'

$files = Get-ChildItem $SourceFolder | where {$_.extension -in ".wav"} | select -expand basename

 # Out FileName, year and month
    $Year = $files.Substring(0,4)
    $Month = $files.Substring(4,2)
    $Day = $files.Substring(6,2)

foreach ($file in $files)

{

    # Set Directory Path
    $Directory = $targetFolder + "\" + $Year+$Month + "\" + $Day

    # Create directory if it doesn't exsist
    if (!(Test-Path $Directory))
    {
    New-Item $Directory -type Directory
    }

    [int]$percent = $i / $numFiles * 100

    # Move File to new location
    $file | Copy-Item -Destination $Directory

    Write-Progress -Activity "Copying ... ($percent %)" -status $_  -PercentComplete $percent -verbose
    $i++
}

Write-Host 'Total number of files read from directory '$SourceFolder ' is ' $numFiles
Write-Host 'Total number of files that was copied to '$targetFolder ' is ' $i
Read-host -prompt "Press enter to complete..."
clear-host;
```

The files are not moving to the folder and I am getting error in the file names

Example

```
C:\Archive\2019 2019\2019 08 2019 08\22 22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$files` is named appropriately plural as a variable that could contain many files.
But when you go to retrieve the date parts, you use call it once, on the whole collection of file**s**, instead of on each individual `$file` (which is the variable you have inside the loop which iterates over the collection of files).

So you want to set the date variables *inside* the loop, on every iteration, so that it's related to the *current* file.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $SourceFolder | where {$_.extension -in ".wav"} | select -expand basename

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $Year = $file.Substring(0,4)
    $Month = $file.Substring(4,2)
    $Day = $file.Substring(6,2)

   $Directory = $targetFolder + "\" + $Year+$Month + "\" + $Day

# etc
}
```

Also the pattern you laid out in your question doesn't seem to be what you're setting, so I'm a little confused how your output looks like it does.

What you have here:

```
$Directory = $targetFolder + "\" + $Year+$Month + "\" + $Day
```

Should produce: `C:\Archive\201908\22` even though you want `C:\Archive\2019\201908\22`.

To produce what you wanted the line should be like this:

```
$Directory = $targetFolder + "\" + $Year + "\" + $Year+$Month + "\" + $Day
```

By the way you can use variables directly in double-quoted strings:

```
$Directory = "$targetFolder\$Year\$Year$Month\$Day"
```

Comment: for the $directory variable, you can use join-path.

Comment: Thank you Briantist!


Thank you! I can see what went wrong with $file.

I have updated the $Directory code as well. Thank you again for pointing that out.